# Delete a Row in gtk.grid (GTK3+ / Python) in upper populating direction

Tags: python, grid, gtk3

i want to dynamically populate a grid with rows and columns in python with GTK3+ Grid (http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Grid.html#Gtk.Grid), it works fine but until i want to delete attached rows. In that situation it just deletes every second row. No idea why...

Generating new Rows in a Loop:

```
self.__builder.attach_next_to(cell[0],None,Gtk.PositionType.TOP,1,1) #Place a new Row
```

self.__builder includes the Grid, cell[0] a Label to fill the Column. This is how i try to deleting them:

```
self.__builder.remove_row(-self.__v_size_value)
```

i wondered, because it just works with negative sign, but just on every second row. Maybe because i populate them in the upper direction? (i tried it out that way, and its true, when populating down there "position" value must be positive) self.__v_size_value includes the Temporary Row-Amount.

This is how it look when Generating Rows, and trying to deleting them again:

- First -> Generate Rows in a Loop with that Command above (Example: 6 Rows)
- Second -> Try to delete the Rows with that Command

  - Row 6 / remove_row(-6) / Row 6 gets deleted
  - Row 5 / remove_row(-5) / Row 4 gets deleted ??? (Row 5 still remains)
  - Row 4 / remove_row(-4) / Row 2 gets deleted ??? (Row 3 still remains)
  - Row 3 / remove_row(-3) / nothing happens any more (Row 1 still remains)

I wrote a small script that shows this malfunction:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    row = 1

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.box = Gtk.Box.new(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL,4)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Insert Row")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)

        self.button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Remove Row")
        self.button2.connect("clicked", self.on_button2_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.button2, True, True, 0)

        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.box.pack_start(self.grid, True, True, 0)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Increasing Row" + str(self.row))
        label = Gtk.Label(self.row)
        self.grid.attach_next_to(label,None,Gtk.PositionType.TOP,1,1)
        self.row = self.row + 1
        self.grid.show_all()

    def on_button2_clicked(self, widget):
        self.row = self.row - 1
        print ("Decrease Row #" + str(self.row))
        self.grid.remove_row(-self.row)
        self.grid.show_all()


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: That code remove just a row, it can't remove every <anything> row.

Comment: Sorry, i have expressed myself misleadingly. I generate Rows in a for-loop. After that, i try to delete them again. But the "remove_row" just takes effect on every second Row. Example: (Row 6 / remove_row(6)) -> Row 6 is deleted, (Row 5 / remove_row(5)) -> nothing happens, (Row 4 / remove_row(4)) -> Row 4 is deleted, and so on...

Comment: You can edit your question if you think it can be improved. Besides, `remove_row(5)`should remove the row in position 5, if that does not happen then there must be a bug in gtk3 or the python bindings. A [mcve] might help to know what's going on.

Comment: i improved my question, also added a small example of the issue

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, i asked Lazka and he was so kind to help me out.
As mentioned above, Grid use negative positions for attached columns on top. As it do so, removing of a row (for example -10) will cause the other rows to get a a new number up to by one. So the first row is for example -10 again.

Thanks Lazka for helping me out!